# How retrieve sum of list and convert into dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have values in the dataframe column and I have converted the dataframe column into two separate list.

DataFrames are results are like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['ColX','Values']))
```

**Where ColX and Values are the columns of the DataFrame**

Dataframe values are like this.

```
 id        Mycolumn 
 0         (x, 51)   
 1         (x, 0)   
 2         (x, 1)   
 3         (y, 2)   
 4         (y, 7)   
 5         (y, 8)
```

Now I have split the Mycolumn values into two separate list one list contain `x,y` and the other list contain `51,0,1,2,7,8`.

```
[(d)[1] for d in df['Mycolumn']]
[list(d)[0] for d in df['Mycolumn']]
```

Now I need to sum up the list results and convert it into dictionary

```
mydict={}
for k, v in zip([list(d)[0] for d in df['Mycolumn']], [(d)[1] for d in df['Mycolumn']]):
    mydict[k] = v
```

**I am not been able to sum up the results of x and y into a list**

When applying **sum()** I am getting 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

this is my code

```
mydict={}
for k, v in zip([list(d)[0] for d in df['Mycolumn']], [sum((d)[1]) for d in df['Mycolumn']]):
    mydict[k] = v
```

this is the output I need

```
 'x':[52],
 'y':[17]
```

Comment: Can you include code that initializes `df` so that we don't have to do it ourselves for the solution?

Comment: And what exactly is the object in that column? A tuple, a string?

Comment: @tdelaney its a data source and the format is like this

Comment: I don't have an answer for you at this moment, but I can at least suggest to split up your for loop into a clean nested structure. At least while you're working on it

Comment: Right, but can you spend a minute initializating a dataframe with those values? Then we could take that df and write an example solution.

Comment: Yes please ^ I'm also willing to take a shot but you have to provide your data initialization first

Comment: @HylkevanderVeen its a tuple i guess

Comment: @tdelaney. I have edited the questions

Comment: Instead of `df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['ColX','Values']))` you may want to do `df.groupby(['ColX'])['Values'].sum()` which will group by "ColX" and then sum the "Values" for each group. Then you don't have to do the whole list and sum thing at all.

Comment: @tdelaney Not giving the sum with groups

Comment: I wrote an answer including an initalization of the dataframe. I only did 2 rows (lazy) but you could do the same thing will all of your rows in your example. In fact, a sample dataframe before that initial groupby would be useful - we may be able to reduce the work significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second dataframe from the list and do the sums from there. `df.tolist` is easier than the list comprehension and the list can be fed directly to the `DataFrame` initializer, so the first steps are

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0, ("x", 51)], [1, ("y", 52)]], columns=["id", "Mycolumn"])
>>> df[["my_x", "my_y"]] = pd.DataFrame(df["Mycolumn"].tolist(), index=df.index)
>>> df
   id Mycolumn my_x  my_y
0   0  (x, 51)    x    51
1   1  (y, 52)    y    52
```

Next, you can group and sum to create a new dataframe that has one row per grouped item. That dataframe can initialize a dict, giving you a dict of sums.

```
>>> dfsum = df.groupby("my_x")["my_y"].sum()
>>> dfsum
my_x
x    51
y    52
Name: my_y, dtype: int64
>>> mydict = dict(dfsum)
>>> mydict
{'x': 51, 'y': 52}
```

All we did was rebuild a dataframe from the group you already created. You may be able to skip all of this and do

```
my_dict = dict(df.groupby('ColX')['Values'].sum())
```